# Showing Index directory List instead of application

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I currently new in ReactJS, And I work this project using laravel and this reactjs. I have question regarding why when i open my web application intead the application is shown why the list of folder shown to my browser?

Scenario: It happen when i upload the whole project to the server it shows look like this.

[image]

1. Do i need to configure in my files so that when i browse my application it will automatically redirect to the application.

Comment: you need to point your domain to `public/` directory. then your application will work

Comment: HI lucky so the problem is in the server?

Comment: yes problem is with your domain which is pointing to the laravel root directory. which should be public directory inside root directory.

Comment: as our system admin says. our domain already pointed in godaddy hosting site

Comment: you mean you are using shared hosting. right?

Comment: yes it's shared hosting

Comment: do you have premission to create sub-domains?

Comment: nope i dont have permission to create that.

Comment: Can't you tell the system admin to point the domain to the `public/` folder?

Comment: she says automatic pointed to the public.. we have dev and prod folder

Answer (score 0):

You must visit the `public` directory of your project or if you use virtual host, set the `public` directory as the entrance.

Comment: what do you mean @Rouhollah?

Comment: What do you type in your browser to see your project?

Comment: this one www.xxxxxxxx.com etc

Comment: Have you uploaded the project to a host?

Comment: i use godaddy hosting site

Comment: Ok, put all `public` directory content in the `public_html` (or probabaly `www` or anything that is the default directory) of your host and all other directories must be outside that directory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184990/discussion-between-rouhollah-mazarei-and-devge).